# CSS sizing to fill parent, staying square

Tags: css

Is there a purely CSS-based way to size a block-level element such that it fills its parent as much as possible, but remains square?

---

**An interesting use case**

I have written a very simple analogue clock using mostly CSS, and a pinch of JavaScript.

http://jsbin.com/iqicuk

It has been written scalably:

http://jsbin.com/emiyer

I would like to scale it to fill the page, but stay in proportion, obviously.

If I set the width and height of `#clock` to 100%, of course, it will be pulled out of proportion:

http://jsbin.com/esubol

Comment: Totally misread the question. It isn't possible :)

Comment: Any block-level element. If you want, you can assume that the element and its parent are both `div` elements.

Comment: I was really hoping you'd say it was an image: http://jsbin.com/avegut. In retrospect, I'm sure you'd have said image if you meant image.

Comment: Yeah, it's nice having that ability for images. So disappointing that it's limited to images.

Comment: If you're using JavaScript at all, you should just use JavaScript for this. I came up with this ugly HTML/CSS solution that involves abusing an image: http://jsbin.com/avegut/2

Comment: That's actually very clever! I might use this as a solution, but instead with a 1 x 1, data: URI embedded image. Do you mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: I will, but it needs a few more tweaks. It doesn't work properly in Opera or IE8 at the moment.

Comment: If you want to keep tweaking for the greater good, go ahead, but I don't need Opera or IE support.

Comment: Hey, I have tried to incorporate your technique into my clock example, and I'm happy to say that it worked, however, one downside is that scaling breaks when the viewport is portrait: http://jsbin.com/isixug

Comment: @Delan Azabani: Maybe media queries can help here?

Comment: I think our minds are alike - I was just editing my question with a media queries-based solution that combines two viewport orientation-specific solutions into one complete solution, when you posted your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A solution in progress**

thirtydot came up with a very clever technique that takes advantage of the fact that images with only one defined dimension scale proportionately, and he harnesses this to size the element. We now have a clock that can scale properly, but only if the viewport width is greater than the height, not the other way around:

http://jsbin.com/isixug

Likewise, if we change `img` and `#clock` to have a defined width, instead of a defined height, then we have a clock that can scale properly, but only if the viewport height is greater than the width:

http://jsbin.com/awucun

---

**The solution**

We can combine the two 'tricks' above, that each only work for one orientation, by using a media query for orientation, and specifying the right 'trick' depending on the viewport orientation. We now have a completely scalable clock, no matter what the viewport orientation or size:

http://jsbin.com/okodib

Comment: Nice teamwork! It's perfect in Firefox, but it doesn't seem to scale properly in Chrome/Safari (if that matters).

Comment: I will attempt to work on Chrome and Safari tomorrow; it's quite late now. Thanks for the heads up! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with pure CSS, but you can do it with Javascript - and I assume you have Javascript running anyway to resize the parent element.

Comment: Why would he use Javascript to resize the parent element?

Comment: I posted before the clock link was added - I assumed he was trying to fit it to a dynamic parent object, not the viewport

Answer (score 0):

Any in flow block level element will already inherit the width from its parent. For the height however you will need to find an alternative.

<s>I doubt this is something you will want to do but if you set your parent to `position: relative;` and then the child you want to make fill up that parent `position: absolute;`. Then specify where it needs to stick to relative to its parent with `top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;`.</s>

However this solution has compatibility issues in lower versions of IE and is rarely acceptable for application...

Comment: Your suggested solution won't actually result in a square; see http://jsbin.com/ifijuv/2

Answer (score -1):

As Jens Roland already said, this is not possible through pure CSS.
Maybe [LESS](http://lesscss.org) is helpful to you.